# Cual es la mejor forma de crear una conexion a la base de datos para una tienda Virtual

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy diseñando una pagina de ventas de productos pero tengo un problema y es que no se como hacer la conexion a la base de datos, he visto todas las consultas y no encuentro la solucion, alguien que me pueda ayudar.

```
$USER = "root";
$SERVER = "localhost";
$BD = "esdefe-store";
$PASS = "";

 Clase para ejecutar las consultas a la Base de Datos


class ejecutarSQL {
    public static $LINK=false;
    public static function conectar(){
        if(false === $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "esdefe-store")){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }
        self::$LINK=$con;
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        $con->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
        return true;
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if(!self::$LINK){
            self::conectar();
        }
        if (!$consul = self::$LINK->query($query)) {
            die(self::$LINK->error.'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
```

**Y este es el error:**
Fatal error: Cannot declare class ejecutarSQL, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\esdefe-store\library\consulSQL.php on line 5

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?. Saludos.

Comment: He intentado con defined, con conexion de mysqli, y ahora declrando las variables tales como $server, $BD, $pass, $usuario, este me funciono pero aun me sale un error, como este: Fatal error: Cannot declare class ejecutarSQL, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\esdefe-store\library\consulSQL.php on line 5

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código que mencionas. Saludos.

Comment: y lo añadí, si alguien podría ayudarme se lo agradecería de antemano. Muchas gracias por su atención y colaboración

Comment: El mensaje de error te está diciendo claramente que ya declaraste una clase con el nombre `ejecutarSQL`, por tanto, no puedes tener otra clase con ese nombre.

Comment: si yo se, pero no doy con el error, porque solo lo declare en esta pagina el cual la llame consulSQL.php, la primera parte del codigo lo llame como configSever.php